# Using extends/super in Wildcards Java/ Find the mistake

Tags: java, wildcard

I have this old exam, which wants me to find 2 errors in the code(there are only 2), but I have found 3.

So this is the code from the exam:

```
    void removeNegatives(List<? super Number> list){
     return list.stream()
     .filter(x -> x < 0)
     .foreach(System::out::println);
    }
```

And the exercise says the method should delete all negative numbers from a list and print out all the elements.

This is what I got:

```
    void removeNegatives(List<? extends Number> list){
     return list.stream()
     .filter(x -> x >= 0)
     .forEach(System.out::println);
    }
```

So I changed super to extends, changed the filter and the syntax of the forEach.

I think I might have gotten something wrong about the usage of extends/super with Wildcards,because our tutor told us that he never puts any mistakes in the head of the method in these exams.

Edit: I just want to know what I apparently got wrong about super/extends. I have already read the linked post and it does not help me understanding this.

Comment: Nope, @mathsstudent. Your prof messed up. I assume your prof is a human and not a god, so, you know. It's a theoretical possibility. As a simple test, take your fixed code, but leave it as `? super Number`.  Note how it won't even compile, as the `x` in `x -> x>= 0` binds to `Object` and an expression of type `Object` is not valid as LHS of the `>=` operator.

Comment: _Neither_ `? extends Number` _nor_ `? super Number` should work here, I think?  I'm pretty certain this code requires `Integer` explicitly.

Comment: I don't think your prof understands bounded and unbound wildcards and when to use them. This situation is more suited for an unbounded wildcard. [More info](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeArguments.html#FAQ10). So, `return`, `Filter predicate`, `System.out`, and the `lower bound` are all issues.

Comment: BTW, mathsstudent,  a `void` method cannot `return` any value... "*there are only 2*"? I see 3 syntax errors. even more if we count that `forEach()` is void itself and cannot be used in a  `return`, and one additional logical (`< 0`) one

Comment: To answer your last question:  `List<? extends Number>` allows a caller to pass a `List<Number>`, `List<Integer>`, `List<Double>`, etc., while `List<? super Number>` allows a caller to pass `List<Number>`, `List<Object>`, or `List<Serializable>`.  Obviously if someone can pass `List<Object>`, it might contain anything, like Strings or Threads or InetAddresses.  So `super` is definitely a mistake in that exam question.

Comment: Thank you all very much, this definitely helped out a lot in understanding more about Wildcards and I didn't even notice the void with the return-statement. Funnily our tutor admitted to not being very certain about Wildcards, so maybe that's why